# How to specify a time based range based on last inserted PK match in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My apologies if this is a very simple question for some.

Lets assume I am querying a very simple table with a PK lookup:

- userid -> int (PK)
- body -> varchar
- time -> int

With time being a standard UNIX timestamp. (seconds from epoch)

I want to return one months worth of results from the LAST entry for that userid.

Now an obvious solution would be to track the time of the most recent insert elsewhere and update it every time a record is inserted/deleted or updated and perform the range query based on that value.

Therefore my question is: Is the a more simple/elegant approach? Am I thinking the right way or is there some built in functionality in MySQL which I am unaware of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built-in function. What you need to do (unless you do that extra table you already suggested) is to do a self join. Something like (untested, from the top of my head)

```
select * 
  from [yourtable] t1
  join [yourtable] t2 
 using (userid)
 where t1.userid = [userid] 
   and t1.time is between t2.time and date_sub(t2.time, interval 1 month);
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas... Thats perfect. :)